# How to scroll up to the bottom on a website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My page consists of fullscreen sections (100vh), and I have made it possible to slide between the fullscreen sections, with the mousewheel.

It seems as it should, and you can scroll all the way down to the bottom and all the way up to the top of the page.

The problem is that when you get to the top of the page, it has to be able to scroll up again, and sliding up to the bottom.

I hope it makes sense.

I have searched a lot online, but I cannot find answers to how to do it.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. Would you please post some code for us to review? Perhaps that'll give us some context of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not sure if I have understood your question ; but here is a solution to scrolling up and down programmatically : https://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-scroll-bottom/